# Replacing custom IDs of links based on query-string using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, url-rewriting

If the current page URL has an argument 'myid1' in the querystring, for each link in my webpage with class 'rewrite', I want the link href's querystring to be replaced by the current page URL's querystring.

I'm using the following code:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                var requestid = new String(gup('myid1'));
                if (requestid!=null&&requestid!="") {
                $("a.rewrite").each(function() {
                    var href = $(this).attr("href");
                    href += "?myid1=" + requestid;
                    $(this).attr("href", href);
                 })
               }
            })
            //gup taken from here:http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html
            function gup(name) {
                name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
                var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
                var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
                var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
                if (results == null)
                    return "";
                else
                    return results[1];
            }
</script>

<a href="http://www.otherdomain.com?someid=1234" class="rewrite">Hyperlink</a>
```

The problem is that the URS's querystring is being added to the links without removing the existing one. How to fix it?

Also, how do I allow one more parameter called 'myid2'. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I don't understand the second part of the question about `myid2`.

Comment: @jfriend00 I want to add another query argument (myid2) which should work exactly like myid1.

Comment: I still don't understand.  You replace all existing query arguments with `myid1`.  Where to you want to put `myid2`?

Comment: For example, if we go to test.html?myid2=9876 the hyperlink should change to http://www.otherdomain.com/?myid2=9876. Right now the change happens only for myid1. I want it to happen on myid2 also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove a prefious query string with this:

```
$(function() {
    var requestid = gup('myid1');
    if (requestid) {
        $("a.rewrite").each(function() {
            var base = this.href;
            var pos = base.indexOf("?");
            if (pos != -1) {
                base = base.substr(0, pos);
            }
            this.href = base + "?myid1=" + requestid;
        })
    }
})
```

Several things to note in this revision:

1. `if (requestid)` tests for `null`, `undefined` and `""` so you can use just the one test.
2. There is no need to use a jQuery object to access the `href` attribute.  It's faster and more direct to just use `this.href`.

If you like fewer lines of code (though not quite as fast), you would do it this way:

```
$(function() {
    var requestid = gup('myid1');
    if (requestid) {
        $("a.rewrite").each(function() {
            this.href = this.href.replace(/\?.*$/, "") + "?myid1=" + requestid;
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: @starryeyes - That was because your test for requestid was not working.  I removed the `new String()` in my answer which should now allow the `if (requestid)` to work properly.

Comment: I like fewer lines of code, but why do you say its slower than the first one?

Comment: @starryeyes - regular expressions are nearly always slower than direct string manipulation.  Usually, the performance difference doesn't matter, but when speed does matter and it's easy to avoid using a regular expression operation, you should.